# Not iframe but i can't find any element on the webpage (selenium python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate the game play for a site but I can't find any element on [the page](https://logigames.bet9ja.com/games.ls?page=launch&gameid=18000&skin=12&sid=&pff=1&tmp=1647271527) relating to the game and it doesn't appear to be in an iframe like other answers on this platform suggested for other related questions. Being unable to find any element i opted to Clicking at coordinates without identifying element and i found this

```
actions.move_to_element_with_offset(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body'), 0,0)
actions.move_by_offset(X coordinates, Y coordinates).click().perform()
```

but i still need to be able to interact with the elements on the site so as to be able to input values and also get values from the site.

Comment: Which element did you want clicked? The whole thing is in a canvas.

Comment: would you mind sharing the link of the site? I will take a look at it

Comment: @xtekky https://logigames.bet9ja.com/games.ls?page=launch&gameid=18000&skin=12&sid=&pff=1&tmp=1647271527